# Can I stop the Steam Android app from logging in each time a game on my wishlist is on sale?

Tags: steam, android

I have the [Steam App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valvesoftware.android.steam.community&hl=en) installed on my Android phone. I also have a few games on my Steam Wishlist.

Everytime a game on my wishlist is on sale, the Steam App logs into my account. It won't open or anything, just log in and show the Steam logo on the notification tray. To log out I'll have to manually log off by opening the app and choosing "Shut Down".

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: FYI that app is horrible and useless.

Answer (score 2):

You can try disabling the push notifications for Wishlist items going on sale and for Steam sales from the Settings > Steam Preferences menu

[image]

This should stop the app from waking itself to display the push notifications.

Comment: It doesn't even show a push notification or open the app. Just logs in Steam. The only way I know a game in my wishlist is on sale is because I get an email notification at roughly the same time.

Comment: @Johno Not sure what else can be done to stop it then. I don't get any notification or the app logging itself in. The only notifications I get is from email

Comment: I'll try searching the Steam forums. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using shut down in the app, go to the settings and use "Sign Out". The app should then forget your credentials and, as a result, be unable to log you in automatically.

Comment: That sounds more like a workaround than a solution :(

Comment: @JohnoBoy probably because it is. The app doesn't do what you describe on my Android... :/